# Deltaspike alternative TransactionStrategy issue

Tags: java, cdi, wildfly-swarm, deltaspike-jpa

In my wildfly swarm application I would like to use deltaspike with the data module, JPA and JTA.

I have defined my beans.xml as this to use **EnvironmentAwareTransactionStrategy** as **TransactionStrategy**.

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
<alternatives>
    <class>org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.EnvironmentAwareTransactionStrategy</class>
</alternatives>
```

However when I run my app this exception is thrown:

```
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.getTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1333)
at org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.ResourceLocalTransactionStrategy.getTransaction(ResourceLocalTransactionStrategy.java:372)
at org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.ResourceLocalTransactionStrategy.rollbackAllTransactions(ResourceLocalTransactionStrategy.java:338)
at org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.ResourceLocalTransactionStrategy.execute(ResourceLocalTransactionStrategy.java:155)
at org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.TransactionalInterceptor.executeInTransaction(TransactionalInterceptor.java:57)
```

CDI used the default TransactionStrategy (ResourceLocalTransactionStrategy) instead of the alternative one (EnvironmentAwareTransactionStrategy) defined in my beans.xml.

The file **beans.xml** is well located in **src/main/resources/META-INF** and in my **pom.xml** I have

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>datasources</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-core-api</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-core-impl</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-data-module-api</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-data-module-impl</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-jpa-module-api</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.deltaspike.modules</groupId>
        <artifactId>deltaspike-jpa-module-impl</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it works by following the example available here: **https://github.com/wildfly-swarm/wildfly-swarm-examples/tree/master/jaxrs/jaxrs-deltaspike-data**

I have made the following action:

1/ removed **alternatives** in **beans.xml**

2/ add **apache-deltaspike.properties** in **src/main/resources/META-INF** containing **globalAlternatives.org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.spi.transaction.TransactionStrategy=org.apache.deltaspike.jpa.impl.transaction.ContainerManagedTransactionStrategy**

Comment: Weld differentiates each bean archive, effectively your WAR file and every JAR file.  When you declare a global alternative, you're forcing deltaspike to override the beans actually resolved to only consider the global alternative.  The alternative would only be considered for your WAR file, not the related JARs.

Comment: If you enable your alternatives using `@Priority` (e.g. globally) instead of in `beans.xml` (per bean archive) it should work just as well. Weld isolates interceptor/decorators/alternatives enabled via `beans.xml` to just that one archive, other archives still see them as disabled unless they have the same entry in their own `beans.xml`.

Comment: Same thread about my question on jboss developer: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/229780 however It seems to be an expected case. But I don't understand why It can't be possible to Produce an Alternative bean for a jar dependancy.

Answer (score 0):

Deltaspike gives use more explainations:

https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/jpa.html

> In case of some versions of Weld - including several versions of JBoss EAP/Wildfly and Websphere Liberty Profile - or OpenWebBeans in BDA mode - which is not the default one, you have to configure it **as a global alternative instead of an alternative in beans.xml**

and

https://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/spi.html#GlobalAlternative

They propose to use the **apache-deltaspike.properties** as a workaround.